# Cancel file upload on server when cancelled from client

Tags: file-upload, kendo-ui, client-server, kendo-upload

I am using kendo file upload control in my application. I select a file of 20 MB size for example. The request goes to the server which needs to upload this document to azure + insert a DB entry pointing to the blob.

Issue is, if the server has all the bytes transferred to itself and the rest of the operations takes sometime (like uploading the file and inserting an entry to DB) and at the same time, user cancels upload from client, it gets cancelled on the client end BUT server still goes ahead with the upload. 
How should I handle this? Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: this is not something that should be resolved using any client-side scripts as I don't believe you will be able to make new request when browser is closing and it certainly wouldn't work when connection is interrupted because of network problems or cancel. Yes there is a cancel event you should call some server side method on cancel to delete the uploaded file.

Comment: Yes, but let's say the upload code on the server takes more time (for a larger sized file) after all the required bits are transferred to the server end. During same time, user closes the browser, I handle the cancel event and try to cancel to uploaded document (blob in terms of Azure). This will fail as the file hasn't been uploaded completely.
There could be some quick fix which I could think of, but I believe this should be a common scenario for almost every other web application. What is the standard approach?

Comment: There is no standard way it depends storage where you are uploading see this post that might help                                                                                                                                   https://www.simple-talk.com/cloud/platform-as-a-service/azure-blob-storage-part-4-uploading-large-blobs/

Answer (score 0):

> This is not something that should be resolved using any client-side
>   scripts as I don't believe you will be able to make new request when
>   browser is closing and it certainly wouldn't work when connection is
>   interrupted because of network problems or cancel. Yes there is a
>   cancel event you should call some server side method on cancel to
>   delete the uploaded file.

Look into this post and answer of Lukas on stackoverflow and make use of cancel event in the kendo upload.

[How to stop file transfer if browser is closed/upload cancelled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397572/how-to-stop-file-transfer-if-browser-is-closed-upload-cancelled)

Comment: Please take a look at my comment above